# Parsing a JSON object in Angular 9 and return the output in a HTML template using {{ item | json }}

Tags: json, angular, http, get, ngfor

I'm new to Angular, I have been trying to use the HttpClientModule, calling the URL from a service and injecting it into my component. I call the method and subscribe to it... now in the template HTML file I get errors and in the console and no response rendering in the HTML.

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';     


@Component({
 selector: 'app-dashboard',
 templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {


 Items:any;

 constructor(private apiService : ApiService ) { }


 ngOnInit(){

    this.apiService.getCats().subscribe(data => 
       this.Items = data);
   }
 }
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<div>
     <h1>
         Transactions:
     </h1>

     <li *ngFor="let item of Items | async as list">
           <p {{ item | json}} ></p> 
     </li>
 </div>
```

api.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';  

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ApiService {


  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  private url = 'http://172.20.10.5:8888/catpeople/cats';

getCats() {
   return this.httpClient.get(this.url); 
  } 
}
```

I get the following error in the browser console.

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
```

I also get this log as well... I know that it's something i'm doing wrong in my Angular code and not my endpoints or restAPI because I can use postman and hit the URL and everything works fine.

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://172.20.10.5:8888/catpeople/cats".
```

Here's the JSON i'm trying to work with:

```
{
    "transactionType": {
        "value": 1052407993,
        "ns": -1024444599
    },
    "payload": [],
    "uuid": "44fe6aef-72e8-4c0f-9158-80925f705694",
    "interrupted": false,
    "triggeringMessage": {
        "transactionType": {
            "value": 1052407993,
            "ns": -1024444599
        },
        "payload": null,
        "uuid": "cc8f2452-7084-43f0-83c2-3d7a10a1c2b6",
        "interrupted": true
    },
    "event": "transactionComplete",
    "status": "INTERRUPTED",
    "nodeName": "node"
}
```

Comment: When I remove the async pipe get a different error: ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: Is it your API response? I don't see an `Array` there...

Comment: Yes I'm not sure what to do when you have an object instead of an array... how can I drill down into the Object and get the properties I need?

Comment: Change the component code to: `this.items$ = this.apiService.getCats()`, the template to: `<div *ngIf="items$ | async as items">
  <p {{ items | json}} ></p>
</div>` and see if it workds. Also, `items` isn't the best name since you aren't dealing with a collection (aka `Arrays`).

Comment: So just got a response without any errors, but I can only drill down into payload:[] using the following  *ngFor : <li *ngFor="let item of Items.payload">
           <p> {{ item | json }} </p>  
     </li>    and I also had to change the component code to Items:any = [];  then it halfway worked... I will try doing what you suggest thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: Aha, so you want to loop over `payload` collection?

Comment: Yes, and all I was doing at this point is trying to render the data. What I really need to do is, check over the response call and after each step in a <mat-vertical-stepper> has been completed on a reactive form. I then want to perform some business logic, in a async manner... I want to subscribe to add in extra functionality to the application (i.e., add countdown timers, and fee/credits) based off the result I get by calling the backend if that makes sense to do it in this approach. Any advice is appreciated! thanks for your help.

Comment: The system I'm working with is completely asynchronous, and has a pipeline design model, (phase 1) a transaction is received via post messages to the network, (phase 2) the consensus mechanism puts transactions/messages into a specific order based on the order in which they were received. and (phase 3) it provides a immutable record of completion... the object you see in the JSON above. It's a shared state network based on a really fast and powerful consensus algorithm called a 'hashgrap'.

Answer (score 1):

You are close. Remove the [`*ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) directive, as it works only with a collection, like an array. Also you do not need [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe since you do not print an asynchronous data. Remove the `*ngFor` and just do

```
<p>{{ Items | json }}</p>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-avewg7)

**Update:**
As mentioned by @developer033, the subscribe method could be removed for the `AsyncPipe` instead.

dashboard.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';     

@Component({
 selector: 'app-dashboard',
 templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
 Items:any;
 public catSubscription: any;

 constructor(private apiService : ApiService ) { }

 ngOnInit() {
     this.catSubscription = this.apiService.getCats();
   }
 }
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<div>
  <h1>
    Transactions:
  </h1>
  <ng-container *ngIf="catSubscription | async as transactions">
    <p {{ transactions | json }} ></p> 
  </ng-container >
</div>
```

And print payload array using `*ngFor`:

```
<div>
  <h1>
    Transactions:
  </h1>
  <ng-container *ngIf="catSubscription | async as transactions">
    <p>{{ transactions | json }}</p>
    <p>Payloads:</p>
    <li *ngFor="let pay of transactions.payload">
      <p {{ pay }} ></p> 
    </li>
  </ng-container >
</div>
```

Comment: Use `AsyncPipe` is a good practice. I'd recommend to remove the `subscribe` instead.

Comment: Is there a way to drill down further and extract the individual values for each property? i.e., transactionTypes: {value: 12345, ns: 12345} . What I want to do here is render it in a  table with the get calls... and in a reactive form push data to the rest api...

Comment: In context of above example, to extract for eg. 'transactionTypes: {value: 12345, ns: 12345}' use 'transactions.transactionTypes.value' and 'transactions.transactionTypes.ns' respectively. Creating a reactive form using the data is a separate topic. I would suggest to refer [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49783050/6513921).

Answer (score 0):

The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted.

In your case you already subscribe to your observable you don't need it.

[More info in the official doc here](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)